# New Gems Not Found in Production with Rails 3, Bundler and RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I recently set up a production server for a Rails 3 app.

On the initial deploy everything worked fine. On a subsequent deploy, new gems that were added to the project are not being found. I am getting `uninitialized constant` and `undefined method` errors when I reference classes and methods from the newly added gems, respectively.

When I originally set things up I was using a gemset with RVM, but have tried to simplify things by removing the gemset and only using RVM to manage rubies.

When I run `bundle list` every thing is there. All of the gem are in `<app_root>/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/`

It seems like maybe it's loading the gems from some other location, like the original gemset, but I have deleted it.

Some other details, I am using Capistrano, of course, Unicorn, my `GEM_HOME=/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286`

Let me know if there is any other info I can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `bundle_install` again after removing the gemset?

Comment: Yes, I did. And I restart unicorn on every deploy. I restarted it several times. I did a full stop and then start and that seems to have fixed things, at least temporarily, but I am not convinced it's permanently fixed. I am going to test it again later with a new gem to see if the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `bundle install --deployment` then you also have to prefix commands with `bundle exec` when you execute the command, like:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If you use `bundler/capistrano` integration then it does it for you in `capistano` but in console you need to use `bundle exec` manually.

RVM was helping you to avoid it with [rubygems-bundler gem](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) - but you changed gemset so the generated wrappers are no more available. You would have to clean `<app_root>/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/` and run `bundle install` again to regenerate the wrappers to avoid typing `bundle exec` again.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems.  It turns out Capistrano isn't properly restarting unicorn.  SSHing into the server and stopping then starting unicorn did the job.  Now to find a fix for Capistrano's shenanigans...